# PHPUnit dataProvider does not get arguments from provider

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a test suite that runs perfectly OK on my local env but on the server i get errors like:

```
Missing argument 1 for ngDateTime_Test::testSecondsSinceMidnightStr()
```

Looks like the providers don't inject values.

I use the same version of PHPUnit on local env and remote server. Does anyone have a clue why it might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in doc: https://www.php.net/opcache

opcache.save_comments boolean

If disabled, all documentation comments will be discarded from the opcode cache to reduce the size of the optimised code. Disabling this configuration directive may break applications and frameworks that rely on comment parsing for annotations, including Doctrine, Zen Framework 2 and **PHPUnit**

Set opcache.save_comments = 0 , to fix this
or
set opcache.enable_cli = 0 , to fix this on command line interpreter, where you probably invoke